# [MongoDB][slow log] what caused the timeAcquiringMicros cost too much，how to solve it

Tags: mongodb

```
planSummary: IXSCAN { uid: 1, relation: 1, time: 1 } 
keysExamined:285 
docsExamined:283 
hasSortStage:1 
cursorExhausted:1 
keyUpdates:0 
writeConflicts:0 
numYields:5 
nreturned:0 
reslen:120 
locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12 }, 
acquireWaitCount: { r: 5 }, 
timeAcquiringMicros: { r: 3520232 } }, 
Database: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } }, 
Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 6 } } } protocol:op_query 3561ms
```

a collection about 1 million entries.

Answer (score 0):

timeAcquiringMicros: { r: 3520232 } is high because the query has to wait for the lock to be released. You can refer to acquireWaitCount: { r: 5 } parameter to understand the number of time the operation had to wait to acquire lock on the time. When the number of attempts made is less, the time taken will be less

Comment: well, the locks at database or collection level were intent shared mode. In WiredTrigger engine, update or insert operations on a document only cause intent exclusive  lock on collection and database.  Why have to wait, or what lock to wait for.